# Lambda handler Context aws_request_id using pytest setup

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pytest, boto3

I can mock **event** in **pytest** to test lambda_handler(event, context) but not able to test **context** and only aws_request_id is used from context. I am trying following.

```
context = {
            'aws_request_id': 'abcdef',
            'log_stream_name': '1f73402ad',
            'invoked_function_arn': 'arn:aws:lambda:region:1000:function:TestCFStackNam-TestLambdaFunctionResourceName-ABC-1234F',
            'client_context': None,
            'log_group_name': '/aws/lambda/TestCFStackName-TestLambdaFunctionResourceName-ABC-1234F',
            'function_name': 'TestCloudFormationStackName-TestLambdaFunctionResourceName--ABC-1234F',
            'function_version': '$LATEST',
            'identity': '<__main__.CognitoIdentity object at 0x1fb81abc00>',
            'memory_limit_in_mb': '128'
}


lambda_handler(event, context)
aws_request_id = context.aws_request_id

Error - 

  AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'aws_request_id'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
aws_request_id = context.aws_request_id
```

is not how you access values stored in dictionary in Python. Change it to

```
aws_request_id = context['aws_request_id']
```

Comment: thanks Matus ! It worked. I will accept answer in few mins.

Answer (score 4):

The AWS Lambda context object is not a dictionary. `aws_request_id` is not a dictionary key, it's an **attribute** of the context object. Modifying your mock to be a dictionary will lead to your code breaking when being run as an actual Lambda function. The correct way to solve this is to ensure that your mock object is an authentic reproduction of the actual Lambda context object.

You could write a simple class and set the `aws_request_id` attribute on it as follows:

```py
class LambdaContext:
  aws_request_id = 'abcdef'

# ...

context = LambdaContext()

aws_request_id = context.aws_request_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the above didn't work for me. Got around this using the following:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@pytest.fixture
def context():
    @dataclass
    class LambdaContext:
        function_name: str = "test"
        aws_request_id: str = "88888888-4444-4444-4444-121212121212"
        invoked_function_arn: str = "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:123456789101:function:test"


    return LambdaContext()

def test_lambda(context):
    my_class = MyClass(EVENT, context)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is old, but it is maybe useful to somebody.

This is how I did it:

```
import json
from types import SimpleNamespace

@pytest.fixture()
def lambda_context():
    """ Generates AWS Lambda context"""

    data = """{
        "aws_request_id": "abcdef",
        "invoked_function_arn": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:123456789012:function:SampleFunctionName-ERERWEREWR",
        "log_group_name": "/aws/lambda/SampleFunctionName-ERERWEREWR",
        "function_name": "SampleFunctionName-ERERWEREWR",
        "function_version": "$LATEST"
    }"""

    context = json.loads(data, object_hook=lambda d: SimpleNamespace(**d))

    return context
```